# How do I use ToggleSwitch with MVVM Light in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I am trying to use a ToggleSwitch with MVVM Light in a Wp7 app.

In the view I have:

```
<toolkit:ToggleSwitch x:Name="toggleAccuracy" 
  Content="{Binding AccuracyText, Mode=TwoWay}"  
  IsChecked="{Binding AccuracyHigh, Mode=TwoWay}"
  IsEnabled="True" 
  Header="Accuracy" 
  Margin="8,0" 
  Height="140" 
  VerticalAlignment="Top"  >
```

The ViewModel contains:

```
private bool _AccuracyHigh = true;
public bool AccuracyHigh
{
    get
    {
        return _AccuracyHigh;
    }
    set 
    {
        _AccuracyHigh = value;
    }
}

private string _AccuracyText = "High";
public string AccuracyText
{
    get
    {
        return _AccuracyText;
    }
    set
    {
        _AccuracyText = value;
    }
}
```

AccuracyText and AccuracyHigh fire to get the appropriate values.

My difficulty is trying to trap the "state changed" event; Checked and Unchecked. If I bind these with something like:
    Checked="{Binding Path=AccuracyChanged}"
I get a runtime error telling me the markup is wrong.

I also unsuccessfully tried a trigger:

```
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
            <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding AccuracyChanged}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</toolkit:ToggleSwitch>
```

I could use RadioButton which work just fine with

```
<RadioButton Content="Up"  
             x:Name="radioButton1" 
             GroupName="UpDown" 
             Width="119" />
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding UpDown, Mode=TwoWay}" 
             Content="Down" 
             x:Name="radioButton2" 
             GroupName="UpDown" />

public bool UpDown
{
    get
    {
        bool ud = settings.UpDown.ToLower() == "u" ? true : false;
        return ud;
    }
    set
    {
        settings.UpDown = value == true ? "U" : "D";
        settings.Save();
    }
}
```

but a ToggleSwitch looks better (IMHO)

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the problem with your markup may be that the [`IsChecked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) Property of the ToggleButton can be three states; `null`,`true`or`false`.You are binding it to a boolean but might want to try making it a `System.Nullable<Boolean>` (`bool?`) to allow for the three states. I believe this is still necessary even if you set `IsThreeState = false`;